# how to replace variables in xml using python

Tags: python, xml

Below is the content of my `xml` file, how can I search and replace the contents of `xml` file? using python

```
<context>

<string name="username" value="test" />
<int name="versin" value="13" />
    <structure name="siteA">
    <string name="name" value="siteA" />
    <string name="ip" value="192.x.x.x" />
    <int name="policy" value="65529" />
    </structure>

    <structure name="siteB>
    <string name="name" value="siteB />
    <string name="ip" value="193x.x.x" />
    <int name="policy" value="65529/>
    </structure>
</context>
```

For example, I want to change the version or username, or some value within structure.

Comment: You have to use a XML parser. Take a loot at http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: i have etree under Lib, am using python2.7, the import of that module as per that docs is not working. (it says no module named etree.ElementTree) is there other way to import that module??

Comment: Use `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Comment: C:\Python27\test>xml.py
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Python27\test\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
       File "C:\Python27\test\xml.py", line 1, in <module>
          import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
        ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree

C:\Python27\test>

Comment: Your file/folder probably is named `xml` (e.g xml.py) as well. Try to rename it to something else.